# How can I execute code in a custom control based on public properties only once?

Tags: c#, properties, custom-controls

I have a control, with a certain property that requires a somewhat heavy init routine be called every time the property is changed.

Of course, the public property isn't required to be set initially, but the init routine *must* be called with a default value.

How can I structure this, so that the init routine is only called once, regardless of whether the designer set the property or not?

Currently, it is called once in the constructor, and then again when the property setter is called through designer code (if specified). What's a good way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the `DefaultValueAttribute` in front of your property, specifying the actual default value of your property, the windows forms designer will not generate code that initializes the property

```
[DefaultValue(0)]
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty { 
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        if (value !=  _myProperty) {
             _myProperty = value;
             HeavyInitialization();
        }
    }
}
```

Properties are only initialized in `InitializeComponent();` if the value specified in the properties window differs from the specified default value.

If you do not need to set this property in the properties window at all, then you can hide it from the properties window with the `BrowsableAttribute`. You can disable serialization (code generation for `InitializeComponent`) completely with the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`.

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public int MyProperty {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's useful to know. if i can stop it with default properties, that's at least an improvement for one case. it's just a shame that in cases where the value differs, the initialization routine is being called in the setter almost directly after the constructors call.

Comment: You can control this. The form constructor calls `InitializeComponent`. This is where your property is being set automatically. Of cause you are free to call any code before `public MyForm() { MyInitCode(); InitializeComponent(); }

Comment: I am developing this as a custom control, independant of any form :3

Comment: Controls have a Boolean property `Created` that is `false` during execution of the form constructor (and thus during `InitializeComponent`), but `true` when the form `Load` event is raised. Checking this property could be an option. Another one would be to use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the heavy stuff.

Comment: thank you~! this is the solution i was looking for. there exists an OnCreateControl event for it, too. the properties are always set before this is called, so it will never call my initialization routine more than once. great! thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean `isInitialized = false` that is set to true in the Init Method.  If you are running the code in multiple threads you may need to deal with that, but hopefully you don't.

Comment: WPF controls don't run in multiple threads, so there's no problem here.

Comment: the problem is that stopping it being fully processed after the first call will make it disregard the property being changed in the designer. i could use the same logic in an event after initial designer properties are guarenteed to be set, but i don't think there is such an event :/

Comment: You can check whether you are in design mode with `if (DesignMode)`. However, this does not work in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to differentiate between cases when property changes its value in "normal" operation and when designer initially sets its value. You did not specify the platform, but I believe this is impossible to do regardless.

This leads me to conclusion that you need to change your design - you need to avoid calling init routine in constructor.

Comment: sorry, this is a WinForms 'Custom Control'. i think you're right though, there doesn't seem to be a logical way to do this, if i can't detect if a property has been set by a form using the control (or not) before it's necessary to run the initialization routine.